# Having Trouble Authenticating a user with YouTubeAPI OAuth2 from an Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have this Azure function, which has the code to upload a video to my YouTube channel whenever there is a video file in the "video" container. The code I am using is from the YouTube API sample code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert . I have taken this code, and I put it inside an Azure function(code below). When I compile and run the function locally, it runs fine and I am able to upload a video using Azure Storage Explorer(below is the console output log) and I see the videos get uploaded in my YouTube channel fine.

However, when I publish the function to Azure portal, and run the function, the function just TimeOuts because it is expecting a UI as it requires user interaction for sign-in. I am wondering how can I get over this OAuth issue? Is there a way to add workflow step in Azure app that prompts the user for credentials? I would like to be able to use my function on Azure without it timing out.

Error when I publish function to Azure:
[image]

Console Output when I run locally:

```
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[3/26/2020 4:46:17 AM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A74A8599'.
[3/26/2020 4:48:27 AM] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='New blob detected: video/Test.mp4', Id=62898b7f-878f-48b2-ace1-dee34a884652)
[3/26/2020 4:48:46 AM] test.mp4
[3/26/2020 4:48:46 AM] Getting client secrets.
[3/26/2020 4:48:46 AM] Done getting secrets.
[3/26/2020 4:48:46 AM] Creating youtube service
[3/26/2020 4:48:46 AM] Done creating service.
[3/26/2020 4:48:46 AM] Trying to upload video
[3/26/2020 4:49:21 AM] Done uploading video.
[3/26/2020 4:49:21 AM] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=62898b7f-878f-48b2-ace1-dee34a884652)
```

Client_Secrets.json:

```
{

  "installed": {
    "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "testindexer",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris": [ "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "http://localhost" ]
  }
}


using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace AzureFunctionToUploadToYoutube
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]

        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("video/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Function triggered by blob." + name);
            UserCredential credential;
            log.LogInformation("Getting client secrets.");

            using (var stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "client_secrets.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
                new FileDataStore("Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-use",true)
                );
            }
            log.LogInformation("Done getting secrets.");
            log.LogInformation("Creating youtube service");

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            log.LogInformation("Done creating service.");
            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = name;
            video.Snippet.Description = "Seattle Channel";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";
            var VideoInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", myBlob, "video/*");

            log.LogInformation("Trying to upload video");

            try
            {
                await VideoInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
                log.LogInformation("Done uploading video.");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Error uploading video: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync

Is for installed applications.  It opens the authorization web browser window on the machine that its running on your Azure function cant spawn a web browser window and even if it could you couldn't login to the server where its running and authenticate it.

## solution

authenticate the code once on your machine. Go to the %appdata% folder on windows and find the credentials file.  Set the FileDataStore to load from a location that your function can understand.  [Filedatastore demystifiled](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/) and upload the file with your code.

## filedatastore

Filedatastore is used to store the credentials return from the user default is not to include it and the file will be stored in %appdata%. You can supply a location.  or no location and it "should" go in the current directory.

What matters is that the library if it detects a file will load the credentials in that file rather then prompting for login which is exactly what you want to happen in this case.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "client_secrets.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("credfolder",true)                              

                );
            }
```

## IDatastore.

If you still cant get it to work the only other option I can think of would be to make your own implementation of Idatastore which would allow you to supply the values from the credential file directly in your code rather than saving it to a file.  Note you only need to send the refresh token. I dont have an example of that exactly but i do have a few examples of how to create your own implementation of idatastore it may help you work it out [Datastores gists](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/a11851d51f13addd70264d01be1928bf)

Comment: @DalmTo, what do you mean by "Set the FileDataStore to load from a location that your function can understand"? I had already authenticated the code once locally, when I ran it the first time. I went to this file path: C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user.
Are you saying to take this "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user" file and copy it in inside my function project folder  and then publish it to Azure?

Comment: When your code runs it looks in what ever folder was configured by FileDataStore for a creditnals file for LookIAmAUniqueUser if it does not find one it trys to spawn a browser window and ask the user to login.  You want to upload the file with your code so it can find it and wont request login.

Comment: @DalmTo so I need to copy this file: “Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user” and copy it to my function folder and then publish it to azure along with the function? Did I understand that right?

Comment: Yes copy the file up and changed your code so that it will read the file from the same directory as your code and not %appdata%

Comment: @DalmTo I think I get it, but I have no idea, how I would make that change in my existing code (above). Could you please demo?

Comment: @DalmTo I am not sure where that block of code you posted above fits in my function. Could you please show where that would go , inside my existing function?

Comment: Look though your code look at mine you will see exactly where it needs to go.  Make sure you read my article about filedatastore https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/

Comment: @DalmTo Just want clarify. When you say "credfolder" is that name of my file(Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-use) or is that actually file path of where the Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-use is?

Comment: @DalmTo I updated the code above in my question, could please check and verify if it's done right?

Comment: looks good when you run it it "should" be putting the token file in the same directory with your code right?

Comment: @DalmTo No trying to be silly, but couldn't I just manually move it from the appdata folder to my directory?

Comment: I havent used Azure function in a while does it have an app data folder because unless you get filedatastore to read from the local directory the library is going to look in app data.  I beleave i may have already mentioned this.

Comment: @DalmTo, So When I ran the function, I see token file in this file path: C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\AzureFunction\AzureFunctionToUploadToYoutube\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user . And then it opend a browser and asked me to "Grand Upload Video To YouTube permmision" and then another prompt to "Conform Upload To Youtube" Are these the expected steps?

Comment: If you run it again it shouldn't prompt you for login.  Try and upload it.

Comment: @DalmTo I am running the function locally, and when I try to upload a video using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, it asking me to authenticate each time now. For any video that i upload, it's asking me to authenticate. Before It asked me only once, but now it asking every time i upload a new video. I mean I can't don this when I move it Azure portal right? because Azure function can't open a prompt to authenticate my self.

Comment: Its asking every-time because its not finding the credentials file.

Comment: @DalmTo But I made the changes, as you suggested. So wondering why it can't read it

Comment: My guess is it cant find the file.   Keep trying if it doesn't work then i suggest you check my edit on idatastore.  Both options do work i have done them for customers in the past.

Comment: @DalmTo Do you think maybe I should delete the token file in the app directory folder? Since it is now in my code directory folder?

Comment: @DalmTo I think now it is finding  the file locally, but here is the problem is it can't seem to find the file when I publish to Azure portal. For example, when I published it Azure portal and uploaded a .mp4 file in my Video container. The functions complains saying:"2020-04-02T07:50:58.551 [Error] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=6aa01186-e3ec-4cc5-9e03-e38cd9281d6d)
Access to the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.0.13139\32bit\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-use' is denied."  ( I posted screen shot on top of my question)  Do you know how I can fix this

Comment: sounds like you dont have permission to read a file you uploaded thats fun.  try creating your own implementation of idatastore that just takes a refresh token

Comment: I saw your code on that, not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Give it a try or google around a little i would be surprised if someone hasnt created unfortunately i dont have time to write an example on it right now.

Comment: @DalmTo I don't think I am able to figure this out. Whenever you have time,  can you write an example of this? Thank you.